# Python read json from site print object

Tags: json, python-3.x

I get this json string from a page:

```
{"lprice":"8330.1","curr1":"BTC","curr2":"EUR"}
```

I tried to access the lprice with this code:

import requests

```
def get_latest_price(api, currencie, real):

    CEXIO_API_URL = "https://cex.io/api/last_price/%s/%s" % (currencie.upper(), real.upper())

    response = requests.get(CEXIO_API_URL)
    response_json = response.json()
    return float(response_json['lprice'])
```

But if I do it like this, I get this error:

> File
>   "/home/malte/Entwicklung/cryptoprice/build/all/app/install/qml/cryptoprice.py",
>   line 16, in get_latest_price
>       return float(response_json['lprice'])
>
> KeyError: 'lprice'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that your

`response_json` is your json-string `{"lprice":"8330.1","curr1":"BTC","curr2":"EUR"}`

Then it should work if you convert the json string into a dictionary with the `loads` function

```
import requests
import json

def get_latest_price(api, currencie, real):

    CEXIO_API_URL = "https://cex.io/api/last_price/%s/%s" % (currencie.upper(), real.upper())

    response = requests.get(CEXIO_API_URL)
    response_json = response.json()
    response_json = json.loads(response_json)
    return float(response_json['lprice'])
```